# Sending the Variables from Layout to comtroller and view in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a  php array defined in "layout" known as `default.phtml` and that array is some thing like this

```
$mydata['abc'] = array("A","A","A","A","A","A","A");
```

I can get the Layout  using a custom defined function

```
$cls = new  cass();
$layout = $cls->getLayout() ;
```

How do I access the same array `$mydata['abc']` in the `Controller` and view.

Comment: I believe the layout is the last thing processed so it wont be available in the controller and the view unless assigned to the layout object before hand like in the controller, view, an action helper, etc.. Why are you defining this in the layout instead of the controller?

Comment: it was predefined and i cannot change it now .Now we need to access that array from lay out how do i do that

Comment: What prodigitalson is trying to say is that all of the processing between the MVC is done first, and then the output of the view is sent to the layout as it's content (i.e. `$this->layout()->content`).  The MVC has no idea what's in the Layout during processing because that part hasn't been touched yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should move this array to your controller. I think it's not a good pratice put data hard-coded in your view.

Also, I think you can't get a variable defined in your view. When you use getLayout() method you are getting not the html code, but the component that render your layout, so you can call disableLayout() for example. But, even if it was the html, before you get it, the html and php code would be processed first and all of your variables would be lost. So, I think you should change your logic and pass this variable from your controller to your view.

Maybe if you post more information about what you are really trying to achieve, we can say the best way to do this.